# Fixed-width table with variable-width columns

Tags: css, css-tables

I need a fixed-width table with columns which have a variable width, so depending on their content, but where the horizontal distance between these contents is the same.

This is what I get:

```
-----------------Table Width-----------------
|----Long Content----|---Content---|--More--|
```

This is what I want:

```
----------------Table Width------------------
|---Long Content---|---Content---|---More---|
```

**Please note the count of the minus-sign in the content cells! When you measure the spaces between the content of the columns, by using a screenshot, you'll notice, that they aren't always exactly the same.**

This is my markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>Long Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>More</li>
</ul>
```

This is my not working stylesheet:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 600px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/12/. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Is the content always only one line long or can it break?

Comment: The content can break. The content can also be wrapped in a div, if this helps.

Comment: Can you show some real content for those columns? Can you use JavasScript?

Comment: I've edited my question, does it answer your question?

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbz5W/) help? And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bnNTD/) with your real content.

Comment: Unfortunately, this changes the width of the `ul`. Damn, why are the column widths are take so inconsistently from the browsers.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dMF7P/) an updated version. The `<div>` is only to show that it fits the width of 300 px.

Comment: Sorry, but the border-spacing seems not a solution for this problem. Make it bigger and the overflow take some columns.

Comment: Yeah but 5 columns on such a small space with an address might also be too tight. I guess, there's no other solution then except calculating the spaces using JavaScript.

Comment: The width here is just an example. I think with JS you're right :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need the left and right padding properties set to 2.5em. However, this will only work if either there are no breaks or every cell breaks its content.

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding: 0 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @insertusernamehere You're right the columns have to be variable in their width.

Comment: I see. Give me a sec.

Comment: How about width: auto in the li rule?

Comment: As a note: table cells do not have margins.

Comment: @witrin What will happen with 2em instead?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you only need to set the padding to the left and right padding properties. I've edited the answer for such.

Comment: You're right, it is a little bit better, but the spaces between the content are not exactly the same. Make a screenshot of http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/11/ and measure the spaces between the `t` of `More Content` and the `C` of Content and between the `t` of `Content` and the `M` of `More`. When you use a example with bigger fonts you don't need measuring anymore to see this. The other thing is, I think that your approach would be a little bit better with `div` container within the `li` to protect the total with of `ul` (http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/13/).

Comment: Your suggestion only works when the text length for each item is the same. Also, div containers don't seem to make any difference whatsoever. In addition, the problem persists if any item list breaks. I have gone further to 2.5em. (http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/14/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly you could try wrap a div fixed width around the ul. then width:100%; on the ul and width:50% on the li

http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/3/

```
#wrapper{
        width:500px;
    }
    ul {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        width:50%
    }

<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li>Long Contentdsdddddddddddd</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a fixed-width table.

Comment: what if you add a wrapper div with a fixed width?

Comment: Sorry, but I need the same space between the centered content in the columns. Please check "This is what I get..." and "This is what I need..." in my question, especially the count of the minus sign in cells. I also need variable-width columns, so depend on their content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your ul tag.  This should do exactly what you want.

```
ul
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ATwqk/19/